# Derivatives in Recurrent Neural Networks

Tags: multivariable-calculus, machine-learning, neural-networks

I am studying [the book](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/rnn.html) of *Goodfellow et al.* on deep learning, and I am stuck at equation (10.19).

Said equation gives the gradient of the Loss with respect to the hidden layer. 
 Now, if the Loss gives a vector, and since the hidden layer weights is a vector too, this would result in a Jacobian matrix. 
 However, with the definition given, the result is a vector with the same dimensions as the hidden layer.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Look up page 199 section 6.5.2 of the book.

This is a straight application of the chain rule of calculus.

**V** is the Jacobian Matrix in this case (eq 10.19) because **o(t) = V*h(t) + c** the partial derivatives are just the coefficients of the matrix (transposed).

There are no assumptions on **h** and **o** being same sized vector.
**h** depend on how many recurrent cells you have in your layer and **o** depends on how many cells you have in the output layer.